# Ruby, factorybot error duplication with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Ii stuck on an error with my app. I'm testing it with RSpec and in my `PagesController` test, at the start:

```
let(:user) { create(:user, favorite_category: "Elettronica") }
```

I get error :

```
Failure/Error:
  factory :user , class: User do
    email { 'test@example.com' }
    password { 'password' }
    full_name { 'a b' }
    uid { '12345' }
    avatar_url { 'http://example.com/avatar.png' }
    role { 0 }
    favorite_category { "moda" }
  end
```

I have 3 factories, all related to User, in different files in folder `spec/factories`.

I'm stuck, I don't understand what is the problem.

My user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and 
   :omniauthable
    devise :omniauthable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, omniauth_providers: 
    [:google_oauth2]
    
attr_accessor :current_password

has_one_attached :avatar

def avatar_thumbnail
  if avatar.attached?
  avatar.variant(resize: "150x150!").processed
 else
  "/assets/default_profile.jpg"
 end  
end

has_many :messages
has_many :reviews
has_many :researches
has_many :active_relationships, class_name: "Relationship",
                            foreign_key: "follower_id",
                            dependent: :destroy
has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: 
:followed    
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name: "Relationship",
                             foreign_key: "followed_id",
                             dependent: :destroy
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: 
:follower


def self.from_omniauth(auth)
   where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do 
   |user|
   user.email = auth.info.email
   user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
   user.full_name = auth.info.name # assuming the user model has a 
   name
   user.avatar_url = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an 
   image
  # If you are using confirmable and the provider(s) you use validate 
  emails,
  # uncomment the line below to skip the confirmation emails.
  # user.skip_confirmation!
  end
  end

def admin?
 role == 1  # Supponiamo che tu abbia un campo 'role' nel tuo modello 
 User
end

def moderator?
 role == 2  # Supponiamo che tu abbia un campo 'role' nel tuo modello 
 User
end
**strong text**
def follow(other_user)
 active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
end


# Unfollows a user.
def unfollow(other_user)
 active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
 end

# Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
def following?(other_user)
  following.include?(other_user)
end
end`
```

Factory user

```
FactoryBot.define do
 factory :user do
  email { 'test@example.com' }
  password { 'password' }
  full_name { 'John Doe' }
  uid { '12345' }
  avatar_url { 'http://example.com/avatar.png' }
  role { 0 }
  favorite_category { "Elettronica" }
end
end
```

pages_spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require "./spec/factories/user.rb"

RSpec.describe PagesController, type: :controller do

let(:user) { create(:user, favorite_category: "Elettronica") }

describe "GET #home" do
it "returns a successful response" do
  get :home
  expect(response).to be_successful
end

it "assigns the current user" do
  get :home
  expect(assigns(:user)).to eq(user)
end

it "assigns search results if the user has a favorite category" do
  get :home
  expect(assigns(:search_results)).not_to be_nil
end

it "does not assign search results if the user has no favorite category" 
do
  user.update(favorite_category: "nessuna categoria")
  get :home
  expect(assigns(:search_results)).to be_nil
end
end

describe 'GET #search' do
 it 'assigns instance variables and renders the template' do
  get :search, params: {
    keyword: 'lamp',
    sort_order: 'PricePlusShippingLowest',
    minprice: 0,
    maxprice: 100,
    instaexp: 1,
    place: 'US',
    minf: '0',
    maxtime: '10'
  }

  expect(assigns(:users)).to be_a(ActiveRecord::Relation)
  expect(assigns(:keyword)).to eq('lamp')
  expect(assigns(:sort_order)).to eq('PricePlusShippingLowest')
  expect(assigns(:minprice)).to eq(0)
  expect(assigns(:maxprice)).to eq(100)
  expect(assigns(:instaexp)).to eq(1)
  expect(assigns(:place)).to eq('US')
  expect(assigns(:minf)).to eq('0')
  expect(assigns(:maxtime)).to eq('10')

  # Add more expectations for other instance variables as needed

  expect(response).to render_template(:search)
  end

  end

describe 'GET #search' do
 it 'assigns a non-empty @search_results' do
  # Stub the external service that is being called in the controller
  allow_any_instance_of(Caller).to receive(:cerca).and_return([
    { 'title' => 'Item 1', 'price' => 10 }
  ])

  get :search, params: {
    keyword: 'lamp',
    sort_order: 'PricePlusShippingLowest',
    minprice: 0,
    maxprice: 100,
    instaexp: 1,
    place: 'US',
    minf: '0',
    maxtime: '10'
  }

  expect(assigns(:search_results)).not_to be_nil
end
end
end
```

The error is FactoryBot::DuplicateDefinitonError:
factory alredy registered :user

Answer (score 0):

You did share the full error message. Therefore, I can only guess that the duplicate error happens on the `email` column, because emails need to be unique in most applications.

Your factory creates the same email address each time a user is created in this line:

```
email { 'test@example.com' }
```

That means you can only create one record at the time. But some test might require creating two users and such test would always fail.

FactoryBot allows creating sequential values for columns that need to be unique. You can enable a [sequence in FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/main/GETTING_STARTED.md#global-sequences) by changing the definition of `email` to this:

```
sequence :email { |n| "test-#{n}@example.com" }
```

Which will generate all users with different email addresses by incrementing a number in the email address: `test-0@example.com`, `test-1@example.com`, `test-2@example.com`...

Comment: Doing this, my app enter in a loop, but not errors appear. If  It Is useful, i can link my repo.

Comment: It would be useful if you shared your user factory, your user model (especially the validators) and the spec that is failing with the full error message.

Comment: Would you mind elaboration on what command you ran when the app entered the loop? And how you know that the app is in a loop when there is no error? What is the full output of the command?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your question you put that the error you are getting is

The error is

`FactoryBot::DuplicateDefinitonError: factory alredy registered :user`

Factorybot will throw this error if you have 2 factories that are both named/are :user

search in your entire app for `factory :user`

And either remove one or rename one as i suspect there are 2.